# WebStorm unknown HTML tag Angular 2

Tags: angular, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Just downloaded latest WebStorm trial to try out on existing Angular 2 CLI v6.2.4.

I did the file open of my root project folder. I see all the files in IDE explorer. However cannot navigate code (<kbd>Ctrl + F1</kbd>) says unknown HTML tag.

What are the steps to configure WebStorm for Angular 2? I googled and also went to `Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> JS -> Libraries -> Add` and not listed there.

For "Create new project" I do see Angular listed but this is an existing CLI project created outside of WebStorm.

Please advise how to setup.

Comment: Try Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> TypeScript, then enable Angular Language Service

Comment: @MarkoCen, that was already checked by default

Comment: make sure that `@angular` node_modules are not excluded from project: Angular support is only enabled if `node_modules/@angular` folder included in index. Please attach a screenshot of your **Project** tool window with `node_modules` node expanded so that I can see what these modules look like

Comment: @lena, as soon as I expanded node_modules (said loading and opened in few seconds). Magically Ctrl B on the component tag in htnl now goes to the component ts file. Until yesterday it was showing Ctrl F1 .. unknown tag in the tooltip. Thanks

Comment: @lena, I don't know how to mark my question as answered by you.

Comment: comments can't be marked this way... I'll add my comment as an answer, so that you can accept it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please make sure that **AngularJS** plugin is enabled in **Preferences | Plugins** and  `@angular` node_modules are not excluded from project: Angular support is only enabled if `node_modules/@angular` folder is included in index. Expand `node_modules` in **Project** tool window to check what `@angular` folder looks like there: excluded folders usually have orange color

Comment: all these conditions were met, still in PHPStorm, Code analysis before commit would show errors for me. I've posted my solution below, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Close Webstorm, delete `node_modules` and `.idea` folder. Perform fresh install and open the project again.

Answer (score 1):

@Gullu, I'solved very similar error (PHPStorm's Code analysis would yell at me) by going where you said (Settings \ Languages and Frameworks \ Javascript \ Libraries), button 'Download', and from there in dropdown I've selected typing for angular and angular-material (took me 2 steps). All was fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

Your dev dependencies are probably not installed.

try `npm i --only=dev`

And if this does not work it is probably the issue with the ide identifying the angular modules.

adding the node_modules in `preferences > language and frameworks > javascript > libraries` might help

### Here is how to do it:

1. click `add`
2. An edit libary popup will open.
3. Name the library anything you want.
4. choose `Node.js core modules` as framework type.
5. keep the visibility set on `project`.
6. we dont need to add anything in the documentation urls.
7. Now click on the first "+" button and add the node_modules directory from your project.

After you have successully added the library, click on "apply" and then "ok".

The ide will take some time depending on your processor but that processing is just one time only.For the subsequent loads it wont take that long. (PS: You can also restart the ide to reduce the memory usage just after all the modules the loaded)

[image]